# Bubble chart without Axis in R

Tags: r, charts, bubble-chart

I'd like to create such chart in R: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

so just a bubble chart without axis, where the bubbles can be randomly scattered and only characterized by the size argument.

I'm interested in doing that in R, where familar options to me requires providing x, y and size variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way using `bubbles` (it is based on `htmlwidgets` so it can be used from the R console, RStudio, R Markdown documents, and Shiny applications.):

```
# devtools::install_github("jcheng5/bubbles")
library(bubbles)

bubbles(value = runif(26), label = LETTERS,
        color = rainbow(26, alpha=NULL)[sample(26)])
```

Which gives:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use `packcircles`. From the documentation:

> The function `circleProgressiveLayout` arranges a set of circles, which
>   are denoted by their sizes, by consecutively placing each circle
>   externally tangent to two previously placed circles while avoiding
>   overlaps. It was adapted from a version written in C by Peter Menzel.

```
# install.packages("packcircles")
library(packcircles)
library(ggplot2)

p <- circleProgressiveLayout(runif(26))
d <- circleLayoutVertices(p)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = id, fill = id), 
               colour = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = p, aes(x, y), label = LETTERS) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdGy") +
  theme_void()
```

Which gives:

[image]